# excel vba - How to get the Day Name of Date?

Tags: vba, excel, date, date-formatting

I have a small code that gets the Day Name of the Dates listed in Excel. But the problem is, it's not getting the right Day Name(e.g. Tuesday).

For Example:

```
sDayName = Format(Day(11/1/2016), "dddd")
```

Then the output produces an incorrect Day Name which is:

```
sDayName = "Sunday"
```

when it's supposed to be "Tuesday".
Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: have you tried sDayName = Format("11/01/2016", "dddd") ??

Comment: Remove the `Day()` portion, it's not needed

Comment: Check [online documentation for Format() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx) where you should find firstdayoftheweek parameter

Comment: @cyberponk Thanks Man. Problem solved. Please post your answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: FWIW - Your code was trying to find the `Day` of `5.45634920634921E-03`, i.e. 11 divided by 1, divided by 2016.  As `5.45634920634921E-03` is equivalent to a date/time of 7:51am on 30 Dec 1899, the `Day` is `30`.  Formatting `30` using a `"dddd"` format first works out that a date of `30` represents 29 Jan 1900, which is a Monday.  But, due to the bug in Excel which causes it to think that 1900 was a leap year, this gets reported by Excel as Sunday.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For your specific request, assuming your date string is formatted as your regional setings:

```
    sDayName = Format("11/01/2016", "dddd")
```

If you want the weekday for today:

```
    sDayName = Format(Date, "dddd")
```

If you want the weekday for any date in any regional settings

```
    sDayName = Format(DateSerial(2016, 11, 4), "dddd")
    'change 2016, 11, 4 for your year, month, day values
```

:)

Comment: Passing a `String` that represents a `Date` to `Format` is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

WEEKDAY Function can be used on this topic and in Vba Codes . For example:

```
Label2.Caption = WeekdayName(Weekday(TextBox2, 0), False, 0)
```

I used this function in when I created userform about date entry to active cell.

Answer (score 0):

i use the answer kadrleyn wrote.

But you have to pay attension that the string returned from

```
WeekdayName(Weekday(TextBox2, 0), False, 0)
```

is not trimmed so if you want to use it in if statement you have to use trim function.

ps. i could not add comment to his/her answer because of my reputation.