# Using excel VBA, Is there a way for me to get the name of the current dates day (eg. Monday)

Tags: excel, vba, date, dayofweek

I know newrly nothing about vba and i am using somebody elses code for now. In this macro it prints in center header the day as "xxxxxxx" In code. What i am looking for is to get the name of current dates day. For example 24.1.2020 is friday and tomorrow the macro would print saturday instead of "xxxxxx or friday". Hope i made this clear enough for people to understand what im in need of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [excel vba - How to get the Day Name of Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40408812/excel-vba-how-to-get-the-day-name-of-date). In your case it's just `Format(Date, "dddd")`.

Comment: jvdV it did tbh.. Not sure how i missed that one, thanks alot